# I found an error message using Termux as I tried installing the pip for Jupyter. Will this error affect my development?

Tags: python, jupyter, termux-linux

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
  Failed to build maturin
  ***ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects***
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
~ $

Haven't tried anything as yet

Comment: Yes, if you need maturin for your development, this will affect it.  Please take a moment to read and understand the rules, guidelines, and purpose of this place *before* posting.  https://stackoverflow.com/tour https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask